# add different plugins to different tab on multipage editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I'm developing two **GEF** plugin and one **RCP eclipse plugin**, I have the next problem:

I have one plugin with multitab editor and i would like to open the editor of plugin on first tab and open the editor of second plugin on second tab.

I mean if I open the file in first tab it uses the editor A, but if I open the same file in second tab, it uses the editor B of second tab.

The rcp pluging only serves as a base for GEF plugins.

is it possible?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but you can use the extension `org.eclipse.ui.editors.documentProviders` in order to implement your logic. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors_documentProviders.html) is a link of the eclipse online help.

EDIT: The problem you would have is to synchronize the both instances, when you open them.Or you can use one with change listeners

Comment: I cant find great information with this extension .. Do you know a site where I can learn more?